# Is there a way to set the indices of a multi index DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am attempting to create a multi index dataframe which contains every possible index even ones where it does not currently contain values. I wish to set these non-existent values to 0. To achieve this, I used the following:

```
index_levels = ['Channel', 'Duration', 'Designation', 'Manufacturing Class']

grouped_df = df.groupby(by = index_levels)[['Total Purchases', 'Sales', 'Cost']].agg('sum')

grouped_df = grouped_df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(grouped_df.index.levels), fill_value = 0)
```

The expected result:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________________________ 
|Chan. | Duration   | Designation|    Manufact. |Total Purchases|  Sales      |   Cost      |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Month      | Special    |    Brand     |    0          |  0.00       |    0.00     |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |    1567       | 16546.07    |   16000.00  |
|Retail|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Season     |Not Special |    Brand     |     351       | 13246.00    |   15086.26  |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |     0         |  0.00       |    0.00     |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
```

This result is produced when at least one of the index levels contains a value. However, if the index level does not contain any value, then the following result is produced below.

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________ 
|Chan. | Duration   | Designation|    Manufact. |Total Purchases|  Sales      |   Cost      |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Monthly    |   Special  |    Generic   |    1567       | 16546.07    |   16000.00  |
|Retail|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Season     |Not Special |    Brand     |     351       | 13246.00    |   15086.26  |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
```

For some reason, the values continue to be autotruncated. How can I fix indices so that the desired result is always produced and I can always reliably use these indices for calculations, even when said indices have no values in them?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the reindex part, as `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()` should take as input the original dataframe indexes (by giving `grouped_df.index.levels` as input you pass only the indexes resulting after the groupby).

This is a solution that wuold work:

```
full_idx = [df[col].dropna().unique() for col in index_levels]
grouped_df = grouped_df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(full_idx), fill_value = 0)
```

If you are also interested in NaN categories, you should remove `dropna()` when defining the full indexes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above solution only returned the same output as the undesired result. Is there some way to set the index?

Comment: Yes, you can add it manually such as: `full_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Retail'], ['Month', 'Season'], ['Special', 'Not Special'], ['Brand', 'Generic']])`. However, please check again the solution previously proposed since it works in some example I have made (consider that previously I haven't re-assinged grouped_df in the reindex part)